# How to make multiple elements (UIButtons) in a row scale equally when turning screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

[image: portrait]

[image: landscape]

(red background of the view  that I placed 4 buttons inside)
I want the buttons to scale out equally when flipping to landscape. I have two constraints on my view trailing and leading space to superview equalling 0, and i have it horizontally centered in the superview. I tried to constrain the buttons to each individually by 0, but then only the last button scales out.

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Ok, after making constraints between each button at 0. and constraining outer buttons plus the view to trailing and leading to superview to 0 AND constraining equal widths on the buttons, I got it working. Should I just delete my question?

Comment: Better to delete and post it to your blog if you have.

Comment: No you should post an answer here on how you solved the problem and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Need to apply following constraints:
Button 1: leading space to superview = 0
Button 4: trailing space to superview = 0
Button 1-4: Equal widths
constraint space between each button = 0

= WIN :)